# How to create a formating and indentaion code in C#

Tags: c#, dll, formatting

How to start with creating a program to format C and their derived code into .net style formatted code so that if I input any program. This program can recognize and reformat by properly adding indentation and other things.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely complex task because programming languages have complex grammar. If you want to format not just C#, but C and C++ too, it’s *even* more complex — possibly impossible because there may be syntax in one language that is not valid (or means something different) in another.

If you want to do it just for C#, you need a C# parser. There are a few free-software C# parsers available:

- [C# parsers](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+parser)

Once you have the parse tree, you will have to walk the tree and progressively output it properly formatted. Some of the C# parsers may already have this functionality.

Regarding the grammar ambiguity: Consider the following line of code:

```
Method(a<b,c>(d+1));
```

In C# the correct formatting would be:

```
Method(a<b, c>(d + 1));  // “a<T1, T2>” is generic; Method has one argument
```

In C and C++ I believe the correct formatting would be:

```
Method(a < b, c > (d + 1));  // Method has two arguments with binary operators
```

Comment: I do understand the complexity. I have no problem using any other free resource. I have got this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/makecodenicer.aspx where macro is available. But I dont know anything about it.

Comment: @Shantanu: What is your question?

Comment: this is tagged 'homework'.  OP is tasked with recreating VS's "Format Selected Code feature" for C# afai can tell.